# Repository or Business logic concern?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

My service method is receiving a message as parameter. This message has same props. This props are used to build a filter for a query. There could be used some logic.

The code which is setting up the filter may looks like this

```
var filter = new QueryFilter()

var predicate = new Predicate()

if(message.Param1 == 1)
{
    predicate .Param1 == message.Param2 + 5;
}

filer.Addpredicate(predicate);
```

My question is,should be this code in the repository or is this a bussines logic concern ?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter that much, but since you have the word "query", which is mostly storage-related, I'd say - the repository

Comment: What if instead of the simple if statement there would be some more complex logic ?

Comment: it depends :) I can't tell you without seeing it :)